# Get Absolute Path of Picture from MediaLibrary (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is there a way to get the absolute path of a picture saved to the MediaLibrary with `.SavePicture` in WP7. This would be identical to the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions` `GetPath` that works on WP8 - but this is for WP7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.
I was making an app where I needed the user to click a picture and then I wanted to bind that picture to a ListBox but I couldn't because you cannot get the absolute path of that picture.

I think an alternate solution should be to get a stream to that clicked picture and save it in your IsolatedStorage. That way you should have an absolute path.

Try this:-

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/12/saving-and-loading-captured-image-to-and-from-wp7-isolated-storage.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to reflect `ShareMediaTask` in 7.8, so I do need the absolute path in order to do that.

Comment: Can't you do that with the absolute path of the same image from the IsolatedStorage?